# Use public directory from external server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

My Ruby on Rails 3.2 application uses the public directory in the projects directory. A normal situation. I would like to access a public directory in another server used by another Ruby on Rails 3.2 application since the files I want are the same.

So my app's public directory currently used: server_ip/opt/RoR/foo/public

Other app's public directory with files: server_ip/opt/RoR/foo/public

I know the files themselves are public, but my application needs to have normal permissions to sub-directories in the public directory.

Not sure if this helps but the application with the public directory I want to share uses Nginx. The application I want to give access to uses Apache2.

Any resources or ideas appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If accessing files is your prime need then you can go with current working directory then go ahead with your required files.

```
 Dir.pwd.concat("/public/your_file_path")
```

Next, if your 2 apps running on same machine then they can be differentiated with 2 different ports.(3000 & 3001) want to access App(running on 3001) then make `localh:30001/required_file_path.`

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Can you give a resource? Your info alone is not enough to make this happen. It is not clear where this code goes.

Comment: let me know which approach you are following out of the two, accordingly I can help you out.

Comment: I have no idea what your answer wants me to do. Or where the two options are.

Comment: will share a better explained small program with you soon.